# html page opens at bottom without any focus element

Tags: javascript, html, focus

My html page loads from bottom even after I tried to blur all focus elements by javascript. I am using following javascript.

```
if (document.activeElement != document.body) document.activeElement.blur();
```

My live page code is [here](https://vastracode.com)

Comment: Upon subsequent reloads the page loads fine. Can you try disabling the rw slider that moves your homepage images (vertically up) and try then?

Comment: The issue is with all sub pages of the website as well. Hence I am sure it is not related to the slider. Try to have a look at something else please @MattNewelski